# why "Unable to load tag handler class "org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag" for tag "tiles:insertAttribute" <tiles:insertAttribute>"?

Tags: java, maven, apache-tiles

I dowloaled and did everything with apache tiles but it don't deploy file jar, please help me. In addition, I also had the same problem with the sitemesh decorator. I use netbean 15, jdk 8 and tomcat 8, netbeans also give some hint about the code Apache tiles when I ctrl+paste, but it still warning not deploy. The URI cannot be resolved in either xml
`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33RQw.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcDqJ.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETY68.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2X6j.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBMqP.png)`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as [properly formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).